# why is .net 2.0 faster then 4.0

Tags: c#

I wanna test my computers performance
so I ran this code

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
        Int64 i = 0;
        do
        {
            i++;
        } while (dt.AddSeconds(10) >= DateTime.Now);

        this.textBox1.Text = i.ToString("n0");
    }


}
```

when I select .NET Framework 2.0 I get a result of 33 Million
but when I select 4.0 I get only 9 Million

Comment: 4.0 has 2 versions worth of bloat tacked on?

Comment: @MarcB: I'd disagree a lot of optimizations went in to v4.

Comment: Are both of them "release" mode (not debug), executed outside of the IDE? Unless they are, any comparison is meaningless. It could even mainly be intellitrace logging things in the debugger.

Comment: Are you in debug more or release mode? Are you priming the test code to eliminate the jitter noise?

Comment: Did you run each several times in a row?  Remember that when you switch target versions it has to be recompiled into MSIL, and then JIT compiled to machine code.  When you switch versions run it at least once to get the MSIL and JIT compilation done, then run it again and use those numbers.

Comment: You're not really meant to do long-running operations in the GUI thread. It could be that there are differences in the implementation of the message pump which is causing the process to run slower.

Comment: Is your build set to "x86" when you're running on a 64-bit machine (default in VS2010)? Different JITs optimize the loops differently. Try setting your build to "Any CPU".

Comment: Voting to close.  There's not enough information in the question to give a definitive answer. As all the comments have shown, there are many variables that need to be weeded out before this becomes an answerable question.  I'd suggest that, after filtering out all other possible causes using the comments here, it may be answerable, but as it stands, it's generating a lot of questions and things to eliminate, but no definitive answer in sight.

Comment: Run your code with .Net 4.0.3 and post result for us.

Comment: One last comment and then I'll shush.  If you want to measure performance, the MSDN documentation on DateTime.Now says this:  *The Now property is frequently used to measure performance. However, because of its low resolution, it is not suitable for use as a benchmarking tool. A better alternative is to use the Stopwatch class.*

Answer (score 1):

Not really an anwer, but too long for a comment... The issue with the code in the question seems to stem indeed from a difference in performance between .NET 2 and 4. Specifically I'm seeing DateTime.Now being much slower in .NET 4 than in 2.0.

The output of the test console application below (after multiple tries) is around 300, 310 milliseconds for .net 2 and 1050, 1090 milliseconds on .NET 4.

Posting the code so others can try on other platforms, configurations. I'm on Windows 7-64 bits, compiling in release mode.

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        const int m = 1000000;
        DateTime d;

        Stopwatch s1 = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
        {
            d=DateTime.Now;
        }
        s1.Stop();

        Stopwatch s2 = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
        {
            DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(10);
        }
        s2.Stop();

        Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}",s1.ElapsedMilliseconds,s2.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        Console.Read();
    }
}
```